# Question about closures and functions in swift

Tags: swift

```
numbers.map({ (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
})
```

Could somebody explain this code? I think numbers is an array here but map is just a function in the swift library right? Like it's a function that already exists and there exists a version of this function that takes an int function that returns an int? Is that it? Well this is a closure I guess and not an int function but can I think of both those as the same as well? Or is a closure and a function different?

Comment: I might refer you to the `map` examples in [The Swift Programming Language: Closures: Trailing Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102).

Comment: The problem is that everyone, including Apple (but not including me, of course), uses the word "closure" incorrectly. Closure is a behavior, not a syntactic element. All functions in Swift behave as closures. The thing in curly braces is a _function body_. `map` takes a function as its argument. That function can be _expressed_ in many ways: the name of a function, an (anonymous) function body like this one, etc.

Comment: @Rob The way the OP has written this is _not_ a case of trailing closure syntax. There _is_ a thing that Apple calls trailing closure syntax, which is merely a syntactically sugared way of writing a function body when used as an argument; but this isn't that. It's just a function body used as argument, plain and simple.

Comment: Lol. Matt, I didn't say he was using trailing closure syntax. I was simply referring him to the examples of `map` in that is in that section, which is a useful introduction to the topic. I think that if the OP went through that chapter of [The Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html), many of his questions would be answered.

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I think `numbers` is an array ...

Yes, one might infer from the name `numbers` and from its subsequent usage that it is an array, but you haven't shared its declaration, so technically we cannot be sure. But let us assume for a second that it is an array of integers.

> ... but `map` is just a function in the swift library right?

Yes, it is.

> Like it's a function that already exists and there exists a version of this function that takes an int function that returns an int?

Technically, not quite. There is not a rendition of `map` that specifically “takes an int function that returns an int”. It is a “[generic](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)” function that just takes a “[closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)” and returns an array of elements whose type is dictated by the closure return type. In your example, that closure just happens to take an integer and returns an integer (and thus, in this case, `map` will return an array of those integers). But it just as easily could just be one that returns something else. E.g.,

```swift
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let strings = numbers.map({ (number: Int) -> String in
    return "Value is \(number)"
}

print(strings) // ["Value is 1", "Value is 2", "Value is 3"]
```

But this is the exact same `map` function. It is just a question of what closure you supply to it. It is one of the reasons that we use closures, that not only can the application programmer supply their own code to be applied to each element in the array, but they can return whatever type they need for each element, too.

---

As an aside, consider your example:

```swift
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let results = numbers.map({ (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
})
```

First, we would generally use “[trailing closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)” syntax, eliminating the parentheses:

```swift
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let results = numbers.map { (number: Int) -> Int in
    let result = 3 * number
    return result
}
```

And you might simplify the closure:

```swift
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let results = numbers.map { (number: Int) -> Int in
    return 3 * number
}
```

And we might let the compiler infer the parameter and return types:

```swift
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let results = numbers.map { number in
    return 3 * number
}
```

And we might even use “shorthand argument names”, where `$0` refers to the first argument, `$1` the second, etc. And, when there is only one line of code, you can even omit the `return` keyword. E.g.,

```swift
let numbers = [1, 2, 3]
let results = numbers.map { $0 * 3 }
```

These are all equivalent to the example you provided in your question. In practice, one would generally use one of these simplified renditions (or a permutation thereof), reducing the amount of syntactic noise in the code.

Comment: But this is still a little weird to me because it's not like I'm actually giving any input here so when I put a closure like that like { (number: Int) -> Int in blah blah where are the numbers actually coming from? This is like function syntax but I don't really see any input it seems like it's just taking each number from the array

Comment: In my examples above, `numbers` is an array containing the values 1, 2, and 3. So `map` calls that closure three times, first passing 1, calling it again with 2, and then calling it a third time with 3. The resulting array is an array of the three results of those three calls to the closure.

Comment: @jayblosem11 - It might be helpful to just look at the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/29e0a31941e609bb7d19ff26dba177cdb25c9d3b/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1200) for `map`. It basically builds an array, appending the result of each call of the [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/map(_:)-87c4d) closure (one call for each element in the collection).